# Problemas com posicionamento de ícones

Tags: html, css

Bom dia amigos,

estou com um amigo criando um site para colocar em pratica nossos estudos, só que estamos com um grande problema neste botões de rede social, não conseguimos posicionar esta imagem no centro dos círculos, alguém pode nós dar uma luz?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está o código HTML/CSS:

```css
/REDE SOCIAL INTERATICA INICIO/ section {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 90px;
}

.rede {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 30px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.rede#facebook {
  background-color: #2372a3;
}

.rede#twitter {
  background-color: #0084b4;
}

.rede#instagram {
  background-color: #3f729b;
}

.rede#snap {
  background-color: #fc0;
}

.rede#plus {
  background-color: #dd4b39;
}

.rede#youtube {
  background-color: #b00;
}

.icone {
  padding: 3px;
  width: 3%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: 15%;
  transform: translate(15%, 15%, 1%);
  float: right;
}

/REDE SOCIAL FINAL/
```

```html
<h1>Atari Mania</h1>

<section>
  <div class="rede" id="facebook">
    <img class="icone" src="imagens/facebook.png" />
  </div>

  <div class="rede" id="twitter">
    <img class="icone" src="imagens/twitter.png" />
  </div>

  <div class="rede" id="instagram">
    <img class="icone" src="imagens/instagram.png" />
  </div>

  <div class="rede" id="snap">
    <img class="icone" src="imagens/snap.png" />
  </div>

  <div class="rede" id="plus">
    <img class="icone" src="imagens/plus.png" />
  </div>

  <div class="rede" id="youtube">
    <img class="icone" src="imagens/youtube.png" />
  </div>
</section>
```

desde já agradeço pro qualquer ajuda!

Comment: já pensou em usar [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/)? Muito mais simples e rápido, podendo também personalizar com suas cores, formatos e tamanhos

Comment: Bom você pode tentar usar o valor de width em pixel ao invés de porcentagem, assim ele não fica se redimensionando conforme o tamanho da tela, levando ele a mudar de posição.

Comment: Eu acabei de ver aqui o Font Awesome, vou estudar ele bem pra criar esse sistema.

Comment: Vou tentar aqui para ver se muda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente é alguma parte do código externa que está interferindo. Ex. algum position em uma classe externa ou variação do width.

Como a ideia é por em pratica estudos, sugiro utilizar um framework para criação de views ex Bootstrap (https://getbootstrap.com/) Seguir e utilizar seus conceitos de Grid faz com que o seu site não tenha este tipo de problemas e ainda por cima faça utilizando conceitos de mobile-first.

Você pode obter utilizar ícones do IconFinder (https://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=youtube&price=free)

Comment: Obrigado amigo, vou dar uma estudada nisso aí.

Answer (score 3):

J.G o seu código está muito perto de dar certo, apesar do Bootstrap facilitar as coisas evite ele por agora. O melhor que vc pode fazer primeiro é aprender os fundamentos do HTML e CSS antes de sair usando qualquer *framework* que já traz as coisas prontas. Não se prenda a muletas por enquanto comece aprendendo andando com sus próprias pernas, até pq pelo seu código já vejo que esta no caminho certo!

Agora vamos a resposta que é o que interessa. Como falei seu código está quase certo. no HTML eu nem precisei mexer, e no CSS só arrumei 2 ou 3 linhas.

Na classe `.rede` precisei colocar `position:relative`, para que as imagens dentro das bolinhas assumam essa classe como fonte de referência de tamanho e posição.

E na classe `.icone`  só precisei ajustar o `top` e `left` e ajustar o `transform:translate` que vc estava usando de forma erra e pronto. Agora sua imagem está alinhada no centro das bolinhas.

Veja o resultado como ficou!

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

section {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 90px;
  text-align: center;
}

.rede {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  /* float: right; */
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 30px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.rede#facebook {
  background-color: #2372a3;
}

.rede#twitter {
  background-color: #0084b4;
}

.rede#instagram {
  background-color: #3f729b;
}

.rede#snap {
  background-color: #fc0;
}

.rede#plus {
  background-color: #dd4b39;
}

.rede#youtube {
  background-color: #b00;
}

.icone {
  padding: 3px;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<h1>Atari Mania</h1>

<section>
    <div class="rede" id="facebook">
    <img class="icone" src="http://placeskull.com/50/50" />
    </div>

    <div class="rede" id="twitter">
    <img class="icone" src="http://placeskull.com/50/50" />
    </div>

    <div class="rede" id="instagram">
    <img class="icone" src="http://placeskull.com/50/50" />
    </div>

    <div class="rede" id="snap">
    <img class="icone" src="http://placeskull.com/50/50" />
    </div>

    <div class="rede" id="plus">
    <img class="icone" src="http://placeskull.com/50/50" />
    </div>

    <div class="rede" id="youtube">
    <img class="icone" src="http://placeskull.com/50/50" />
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, usei aqui e realmente ficou show! Irei usar como referencia.